# What does \n\r mean?

Tags: ascii

When reading from a pseudo-terminal via java, I'm seeing "\n\r" in the text. What is that representative of? Note its not "\r\n" which I'm familiar with.

Comment: A bit more context would help.  `\r` is a carriage return which often means that the cursor should move to the leftmost column, while `\n` is a line feed which moves the cursor to the next line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\n` is a line feed (ASCII code 10), `\r` is a carriage return (ASCII code 13).

Different operating systems use different combinations of these characters to represent the end of a line of text. Unix-like operating systems (Linux, Mac OS X) usually use only `\n`. MS-DOS and Windows use `\r\n` (carriage return, followed by a line feed).

The code you're using uses `\n\r` (line feed, carriage return). There are operating systems that use that sequence, but probably it's a mistake and it should have been `\r\n`.

See [Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) on Wikipedia.

If you're programming in Java and you want to know what the newline sequence is for the operating system that your program is running on, you can get the system property `line.separator`:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```