# String comparison giving wrong result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, ejs

I have below months.txt file in which I have the content:

```
January
February
March
```

Then I read the content of the file into an array using below code:

```
var data=fs.readFileSync('./months.txt');
data=data.toString().split("\n");
```

Then I send this data array as ejs variable to front end(data array has name of all months):

```
res.render("file.ejs",{months: data});
```

I am using the `data` array in ejs file as:

```
<select name="month">
<option value="<%= months[0] %>">January</option>
<option value="<%= months[1] %>">February</option>
<option value="<%= months[2] %>">March</option>
</select>
```

When the chosen item in above dropdown is sent to the server, correct month name is being prined, but now comes the problem. If I select February and do this:

```
console.log(req.body.month);// prints February
console.log(req.body.month=="February");// prints false
```

What could be the possible reason behind this? Any suggestions are most welcomed!

*EDIT*:
I just printed data array and it contains this strange elements:
`[ 'January\r', 'February\r', 'March\r' ]`
What is this `\r`? Maybe because of this comparison is returning false.

Comment: [What does `\r` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745381/what-does-n-r-mean)

Comment: My guess is your text file has newlines encoded as `\r\n` and when you split it using `\n` it keeps the `\r`.

Comment: take a look at this: [What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n#:~:text=They're%20different%20characters.,printing%20on%20the%20next%20line.)

Answer (score 0):

On windows computers, linebreaks are denoted by \r\n rather than \n. Using `.split('\n')` would likely leave in the \r, which is making the comparison false.

Changing your `data.toString().split('\n')` to `data.toString().split('\r\n')` would likely remove those.

Comment: I'd suggest doing `data.toString().split('\n').map(x => x.replace('\r', ''))` to be still able to work even in non-windows environments

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend: `data.toString().replace('\r','').split('\n')`